# Is it possible to implement server side rendering with existing react application

Tags: reactjs, web-crawler, server-side-rendering, renderer, google-crawlers

React version - 18.2.0

Web URL : http://medicasapp.com/

Above application was developed in React JS and is already in live .We are unable to inspect Meta title and description, even though using react-helmet

We need your help to convert CSR to SSR rendering.

Comment: There are many frameworks that can help with this. The one I know is Next JS. You can look into two ways, [Pages Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering) or [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering)

Answer (score -1):

The answer is **YES!**

**But** you'll need a few additional things.

1. You need to run **NodeJS** on your server.
2. You need to **implement a backend framework** (like Express).
3. You need to **render the React application on the server** and then send it to the client side.

I have and **example repo** in github: https://github.com/iamalinski/react-express-ssr